# Adding a square polygon of a set size around a point using leaflet.js

Tags: leaflet, polygon

Bit of a weird one I hope someone can help out with.

In leaflet, once the user has entered a lat/lng and added a point to the map I want to be able to also add a 10km square around that point.

I've tried looking around for a calculation to find the corners of the square x Km away but haven't dug anything up. But surely there's an easier way!

Does anyone have any thoughts? It'd be lovely to just say L.polygon then pass in a centre point and a square size.

Thanks,

Tayler

Comment: You would probably need an external library like [Turf.js](http://turfjs.org/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Initialize a `L.Circle` on your desired latitude/longitude with a radius of 5000 meters, grab the boundaries and use them to initialize a `L.Rectangle`:

```
new L.Rectangle(new L.Circle([0, 0], 5000).getBounds())
```

Comment: Nice and simple trick, as always! ;-) Just a slight inaccuracy in vertical dimension, but for 10km that should be acceptable, if not negligible. A nice page to compare quickly with Leaflet geodesy: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/leaflet-geodesy/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a example working with leaflet 1.9

```js
    const perimeter = 100_000 // we want a rectangle with a 100km perimeter
    const rectangleCenter = [13, -13] // center of the rectangle
    const circle = L.circle(rectangleCenter, { radius: perimeter / 8 }).addTo(map)
    const { _northEast, _southWest } = circle.getBounds()
    map.removeLayer(circle)
    L.rectangle([[_northEast.lat, _northEast.lng], [_southWest.lat, _southWest.lng]], { color: "#ff7800", weight: 1 }).addTo(map)
```