# How to draw 100m x 100m Rectangle using leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, latitude-longitude, geography

I need to draw a rectangle on the map that's approximately 100mx100m. But as you know it's only possible by using latitude and longitude and for some reason I can't seem to make it work using the formulas that supposedly solve this issue.

This here was my most recent attempt:

```
var data = {
    sw: {
        lat: e.layer.getLatLngs()[1].lat,
        lng: e.layer.getLatLngs()[1].lng + (100 / 6378137) * (180 / Math.PI) / Math.cos(e.layer.getLatLngs()[1].lng * Math.PI / 180)

    },
    nw: {
        lat: e.layer.getLatLngs()[1].lat,
        lng: e.layer.getLatLngs()[1].lng
    },
    se: {
        lat: e.layer.getLatLngs()[1].lat - (100 / 6378137) * (180 / Math.PI),
        lng: e.layer.getLatLngs()[1].lng + (100 / 6378137) * (180 / Math.PI) / Math.cos(e.layer.getLatLngs()[1].lng * Math.PI / 180)
    },
    ne: {
        lat: e.layer.getLatLngs()[1].lat - (100 / 6378137) * (180 / Math.PI),
        lng: e.layer.getLatLngs()[1].lng
    },
}
e.layer.setLatLngs([data.sw, data.nw, data.ne, data.se]); //e.layer.getLatLngs()[0], ...[1], ...[2], ...[3]
```

Comment: If you know the center coordinates and you are drawing a square, you would be interested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36041765/adding-a-square-polygon-of-a-set-size-around-a-point-using-leaflet-js/36046425#36046425

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got to work with the cosine of the latitude, not the cosine of the longitude. Other than that, your numbers are right.

For reference, see also http://playground-leaflet.rhcloud.com/jop/edit?html,output

Comment: Can't believe I missed that! Thank you so much!